# How to give an edited "AppleScript app" necessary permissions in Ventura?

Tags: applescript, permission

Since updating to macOS Ventura, I’m having a lot of permissions trouble with AppleScripts saved as apps that worked in Monterey (and previous versions of macOS) and seem to work only on the initial run in Ventura.  Anytime you edit the script inside the app, the permissions (at least for assistive access) will never be restored.  I’m familiar with these errors in Monterey and previous OS versions, such as:

“not allowed to send keystrokes" or "not allowed assistive access":

[image] [image]

and the solution in Monterey was to add the AppleScript saved as an app to various sections in the “Security and Privacy” system preferences, like in the “Automations” tab, “full disk access” tab, ”input monitoring” tab,  “accessibility” tab, etc..  And you would have to toggle those permissions off and on if you ever edited the script inside the app.  And that always worked in past macOS versions to satisfy the permissions issues...

but in Ventura, that doesn’t seem to work. I still get the "assistive access" permissions error.  So I keep having to create entirely new AppleScript apps in order to get it to run without a permissions error, which is annoying to say the least (especially since I am having to make little trial and error edits from time to time to work around interface issues).  I could do that in Script Editor instead, but I still have to copy code at least once.

Can anyone tell me how to adjust the permissions so that copying the AppleScript to a new file saved as an app is not necessary to avoid permissions issues?

*Also, incidentally, the original versions of the applescripts saved as apps in previous OS versions won't run at all no matter what I do to the permissions.  If you run them, you get:*

[image]

In this specific case (my `Galaxy.app` script-app), the process went like this:

1. Ran the original script (from before the update to Ventura) and got the "cannot be opened" error
2. Copied the code to a new script saved as an app
3. Ran and got the keystroke permissions error (because I forgot to set all the permissions before running it)
4. Adjusted permissions for the keystroke permissions issue
5. Ran and got no keystroke error, but discovered that I needed a longer delay to wait for the keystrokes to finish in ventura (so it never got to the line of code that required assistive access)
6. Tweaked the delay in the code
7. Toggled all the permissions off and back on (as used to work in previous macOS versions)
8. Ran and got the assistive access permissions error despite having toggled that app's permissions, and no matter how much I toggled permissions or removed and re-added the app to the assistive access prefs pane, that permissions error would not go away
9. So I had to copy again to a new script-app, assign permissions, and only then, I avoided all the permissions errors.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Were you able to fix it without creating a new script-app?

Comment: Note, I usually add a little icon to my AppleScript apps. Don't think that's relevant, but it's in the screenshots, so I thought I would mention it. And whenever I create a new copy of the app, I copy the icon too.